# Applying a Single Image to Cover a Group of Keys in HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a virtual keyboard project and I'm trying to apply a single background image to cover an entire group of keys without affecting the layout. I've tried a few approaches, but I'm encountering difficulties with CSS positioning and overlaying.

When I wrap a group of keys in a  element to apply a background image, the key layout gets disrupted. The keys are no longer aligned correctly, and the spacing between them changes.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const g1Keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key.g1");

  g1Keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.add("hovered");
      });
    });

    key.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.remove("hovered");
      });
    });
  });
});

//G2
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const g1Keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key.g2");

  g1Keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.add("hovered");
      });
    });

    key.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.remove("hovered");
      });
    });
  });
});

//G3
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const g1Keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key.g3");

  g1Keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.add("hovered");
      });
    });

    key.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.remove("hovered");
      });
    });
  });
});


//G4
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const g1Keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key.g4");

  g1Keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.add("hovered");
      });
    });

    key.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.remove("hovered");
      });
    });
  });
});

//G5
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const g1Keys = document.querySelectorAll(".key.g5");

  g1Keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.add("hovered");
      });
    });

    key.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      g1Keys.forEach(g1Key => {
        g1Key.classList.remove("hovered");
      });
    });
  });
});


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const colorInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".color-input");

  colorInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
      const groupClass = this.classList[1]; // Assuming the second class is the group class
      const keys = document.querySelectorAll(`.key.${groupClass}`);

      keys.forEach(key => {
        key.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
      });
    });
  });
});



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const imageInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".image-input");

  imageInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
      const groupClass = this.classList[1]; // Assuming the second class is the group class
      const keys = document.querySelectorAll(`.key.${groupClass}`);
      const file = this.files[0];

      if (file) {
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        keys.forEach(key => {
          key.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imageUrl}')`;
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.keyboard-base {
  max-width: 1085px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(30, 30px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 60px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.color-input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.key.g1:hover,
.key.g1.hovered {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.key.g2:hover,
.key.g2.hovered {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.key.g3:hover,
.key.g3.hovered {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.key.g4:hover,
.key.g4.hovered {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.key.g5:hover,
.key.g5.hovered {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.key {
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  grid-column: span 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.key:hover {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.delete {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.tab {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.backslash {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.capslock {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.return {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.leftshift {
  grid-column: span 5;
}

.rightshift {
  grid-column: span 5;
}

.leftctrl {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.command {
  grid-column: span 3;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.space {
  grid-column: span 13;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyboard-base">
  <div class="key g1">~</div>
  <div class="key g1">1</div>
  <div class="key g1">2</div>
  <div class="key g1">3</div>
  <div class="key g1">4</div>
  <div class="key g1">5</div>
  <div class="key g1">6</div>
  <div class="key g1">7</div>
  <div class="key g1">8</div>
  <div class="key g1">9</div>
  <div class="key g1">0</div>
  <div class="key g1">-</div>
  <div class="key g1">+</div>
  <div class="key delete g5">Backspace</div>
  <div class="key tab g5">Tab</div>
  <div class="key g3">Q</div>
  <div class="key g2">w</div>
  <div class="key g3">E</div>
  <div class="key g3">R</div>
  <div class="key g3">T</div>
  <div class="key g3">Y</div>
  <div class="key g3">U</div>
  <div class="key g3">I</div>
  <div class="key g3">O</div>
  <div class="key g3">P</div>
  <div class="key g3">[</div>
  <div class="key g3">]</div>
  <div class="key backslash g5">\</div>
  <div class="key capslock g5">CapsLock</div>
  <div class="key g2">A</div>
  <div class="key g2">S</div>
  <div class="key g2">D</div>
  <div class="key g3">F</div>
  <div class="key g3">G</div>
  <div class="key g3">H</div>
  <div class="key g3">J</div>
  <div class="key g3">K</div>
  <div class="key g3">L</div>
  <div class="key g3">;</div>
  <div class="key g3">'</div>
  <div class="key return g4">Enter</div>
  <div class="key leftshift g5">Shift</div>
  <div class="key g3">Z</div>
  <div class="key g3">X</div>
  <div class="key g3">C</div>
  <div class="key g3">V</div>
  <div class="key g3">B</div>
  <div class="key g3">N</div>
  <div class="key g3">M</div>
  <div class="key g3">,</div>
  <div class="key g3">.</div>
  <div class="key g3">/</div>
  <div class="key rightshift g5">Shift</div>
  <div class="key leftctrl g5">Ctrl</div>
  <div class="key g5">Alt</div>
  <div class="key command g5">Command</div>
  <div class="key space g4">Space</div>
  <div class="key command g5">command</div>
  <div class="key g5">Alt</div>
  <div class="key g5">Ctrl</div>
  <div class="key g5">Fn</div>

  <input type="color" class="color-input g1">
  <input type="color" class="color-input g2">
  <input type="color" class="color-input g3">
  <input type="color" class="color-input g4">
  <input type="color" class="color-input g5">

  <input type="file" class="image-input g1">
  <input type="file" class="image-input g2">
  <input type="file" class="image-input g3">
  <input type="file" class="image-input g4">
  <input type="file" class="image-input g5">
</div>
```

What I've Tried:

I attempted to use  elements to group the keys and apply the background image, but it's causing layout issues. The keys are not aligned as expected, and the spacing between them changes.

Desired Outcome:

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to apply a single background image to cover an entire group of keys without affecting the layout. The keys should retain their original positions and spacing.

Questions:

Is there an alternative approach to applying the background image that won't disrupt the key layout?
Are there any specific CSS techniques or properties I should consider to achieve the desired image overlay without affecting the layout?

I appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to address this issue and achieve the desired effect while maintaining the original key layout.

Comment: It seems like you're making this much harder than it needs to be. The keys alignment is going to be difficult to ascertain based on screen size, zoom level etc. Why not just style the keys individually based on the existing `.key` elements?

Comment: i didn't get you @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `The keys are not aligned as expected, and the spacing between them changes.` Can you update your example to show this behavior?  It doesn't look like any background images are being used right now.

Comment: i mean for example if i added div for the keys for example like this
        <div class="group 1">
        <div class="key g1">~</div>
        <div class="key g1">1</div>
        <div class="key g1">2</div>
        <div class="key g1">3</div>
 <..other keys..>
       <div class="key g1">9</div>
        <div class="key g1">0</div>
        <div class="key g1">-</div>
    </div>

the aligns for the keys will be different i need to do this so i can apply background my approach now duplicating the image on each key but i need it to be on the group

Comment: I thought at first that what you needed was display: contents on elements of class group - then the children will be placed in the grid. But I suspect this isn't right as you want a background to the whole group. Is this to create a sort of 'stripe' across the keyboard? It might help us help you if you could perhaps provide a sketch of what result you want.

Comment: And could you clarify whether the image is to cover (ie go in front of in the z-direction sense) the keys or is to be behind them (so they are still visible)?

Comment: exactly something like this https://goblintechkeys.com/products/design-studio-custom-design-60-mechanical-keyboard-ansi-white

i want it to be covering the keys its for customizing a keyboards it should be above the keys not below or exactly inside them but not duplicate the image on each key

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1.CSS positioning

```
.key {
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    grid-column: span 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 17px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative; /* Add position relative to enable overlay */
}

/* Apply background image on hover */
.key:hover {
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    background-image: url('your-image-url.jpg'); /* Specify the background image URL */
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure the image is on top */
}
```

Image URL: Make sure to replace 'your-image-url.jpg' with the actual URL of your background image.

Comment: i think you misunderstood what i need what i'm doing that we have gaming shop we make custom keyboards

what i need is when applying background it should be covering the whole keys group 

the issue now is when i'm applying the background its duplicating on each key not covering all of them

Comment: something like this

https://goblintechkeys.com/products/design-studio-custom-design-60-mechanical-keyboard-ansi-white